# Need interdependent button CHANGE and select CLICK functionality by using jQuery. I need to combine them on document ready?

Tags: jquery, list, function, select, jquery-events

The script is fine as far as the over all functionality is considered, but the only problem is the select option value disappeared (I believe `#selectbox` value is not properly selecting the value) when select from option or via button. Basically I need to equal `.btn-itemlist` and `#selectbox` value and move both of them simultaneously. Keeping in mind these values, are generated dynamically and total numbers of both values are same on load. I want both of them dependent on each other on document.ready and remain same by clicking and selecting.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.btn-itemlist[value="0"]').click();

$(".btn-itemlist").click(function(e) {
   var _self = $(this),
   value = _self.val();
  $("#selectbox").val(value).trigger('change');
});

$('#selectbox').change(function(e) { 
   var _self = $(this),
   value = _self.val();
    $('.btn-itemlist[value="'+ value+'"]').click();
});

});
```

Previously, I made the following script and this works fine only when **one function** is used either `#selectbox` or `.btn-itemlist click()`. Simply you can say either select become dependant on click or click over select but both of them are not interdependent. When I use both of them with document `on.load` only first parts executes (in this case `.btn-itemlist`) and jQuery starts throwing an error of:

> " Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

and this error further increases on every click or select of an option.

```
$(".btn-itemlist").click(function() {
  q = ($(this).attr('value')),
  $("#selectbox").val(q).trigger('change');
});

$('#selectbox').change(function() 
{ 
val1 = $("#selectbox").val();
$('.btn-itemlist[value="'+ val1+'"]').click();
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle
[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hilalrehan/1knszvup/6/)

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including the HTML on which this code runs. Just enough to show us what you mean, and reproduces the problem. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to produce something that runs here on Stack Overflow (the icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar).

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Here is the JS Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/hilalrehan/1knszvup/2/

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
$(".btn-itemlist").click(function(e) {
   var _self = $(this),
   value = _self.val();
  $("#selectbox").val(value).trigger('change');
});
```

to

```
$(".btn-itemlist").click(function() {
  q = $(this).attr('value');
  $("#selectbox").prop('selectedIndex', q);
```